# While loop on python

Tags: python

```
def powers(L):
    '''
    (list of ints) -> bool
    Return True if the given list of ints is a list of powers of some
    int x of the form [x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, ...] and False otherwise.
    >>>powers[1, 3, 9, 27, 81]
    True
    '''
    i = 1
    x = L[0]
    while i < len(L):
        if L[i] == x**(i+1):
            i += 1
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I have changed the mistakes you have pointed out for me, but it still doesn't work.. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Why are you using `+=`? You're using it when you assign the new value of `new_l[i]`; that should just be `=`. And you're using it when you're comparing, that should be `==`. Also, you're incrementing `i` before you compare the values.

Comment: Another problem, you assign to `new_l[i]`, but then you use `new_L[i]`. Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: You don't need the array `new_L`. Just test if `L[i] == x**i`.

Comment: The first element of a list is `L[0]`, not `L[1]`.

Comment: If you simply stepped through the code a line at a time you would have noticed all these problems.

Comment: You mentioned `ints is a list of powers of some
    int x of` so from where the value of X will come? Wil it be passed by user of it will always be first element of the list?

Comment: @Barmar I have fixed all the mistakes you have pointed out for me, but it still does not work. Everything I wrote down will come out with 'False'... Could you tell me how to fix this more?

Comment: Add your new script as an update to the question.

Comment: You shouldn't have `return True` in the loop. You don't know if the result is True until you reach the end of the list, and none of the elements failed the check.

Comment: Because list indexes start at `0`, the equalities should be `L[0] == x**1`, `L[1] == x**2`, and so on. So it's `L[i] == x**(i+1)`

Comment: @Barmar can you double check it for me plz? Coz it still doesn't work..

Comment: I am still not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I just noticed that the list includes `x^0`, which is always `1`. So the indexes are not 1 off from the powers. But you have to use `L[1]` to know which number is the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def powx(l):
    i = 0
    x = l[1]
    newL = []
    while i < len(l):
        if x**i == l[i]:
            newL.append(x**i)
        else:
            return False

        i+=1
    if newL == l:
        print(newL)
        return True
```

a = [1, 2, 4, 9] 
b = [1, 3, 9, 27] 
powx(a) // should return False 
powx(b) //should return [1, 3, 9, 27] True

Comment: Fix your indentation

Comment: THANKS! It really helps a lot!! @Davi Rolim

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot!! @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

You must not return `True` inside the loop, because that will end the function without testing the rest of the list. Your function just checks the 2nd element of the list, because it returns in both cases.

The way to know that everything is a power of the number is to wait until the end of the loop. If it never returned `False` during the loop, everything matches the criteria. For some reason, this general concept seems to be incredibly hard for new programmers, as I see this bug pattern all the time here.

```
def powers(L):
    '''
    (list of ints) -> bool
    Return True if the given list of ints is a list of powers of some
    int x of the form [x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, ...] and False otherwise.
    >>>powers[1, 3, 9, 27, 81]
    True
    '''
    i = 0
    x = L[1]
    while i < len(L):
        if L[i] != x**i:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Since obviously the second element (and **not** the first one) in your list is `x`, since it's `x**1`, you can construct the list of all powers of `x` and compare that to your list.

```
def powers(L):
    return [L[1]**i for i in range(len(L))] == L
```